# How to use webmock regex matcher?

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec, webmock

How to match a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/:id/bar
http://www.example.com/foo/1/bar
http://www.example.com/foo/999/bar
```

stub_request(:post, "www.example.com")

Comment: Are you looking for a Regexp to match the URL patterns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`http://www\..*?\.com/foo/\d+/bar` should work for you.

Comment: @BSeven `\.` is escaping the `.` dot character while `.*?` means any character (the dot character means any character) zero or more times (the `*` is zero or more times while `+` is 1 or more times) and make it non-greedy (the question mark `?`) so it stops looking as soon as it hits `.com`.

Answer (score 39):

You can use `%r{}` instead of `//` for your regular expression in Ruby to avoid having to escape the forward slashes in URLs.  For example:

```
stub_request(:post, %r{\Ahttp://www.example.com/foo/\d+/bar\z})
```

Comment: Also, can use many other characters instead of `{}` to close the regex, for example `%r()` or `%r''`

This is helpful because the regex quantity modifier uses curly braces. So if you're trying to match a URL or something with a specific number of characters, like a 36 character API key, use something like parentheses to close the regex.

Answer (score 21):

The second argument to stub_request must be a regular expression, not a string.

```
stub_request(:post, /http:\/\/www.example.com\/foo\/\d+\/bar/)
```