# Rails WebMock against XML request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, paypal, webmock

I am having a hard time figuring out how to match stub_request with XML requests using webmock.

Request:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <env:Header>
        <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:n1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" env:mustUnderstand="0">
          <n1:Credentials>
            <n1:Username>XYZ</n1:Username>
            <n1:Password>ABC</n1:Password><n1:Subject/>
            <n1:Signature>HUGE-STRING</n1:Signature>
          </n1:Credentials>
        </RequesterCredentials>
      </env:Header>
      <env:Body>
        <ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatusReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
          <ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatusRequest xmlns:n2="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
            <n2:Version>124</n2:Version>
            <n2:ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatusRequestDetails>
              <ProfileID>sdaddsadsd</ProfileID>
              <n2:Action>Cancel</n2:Action>
            </n2:ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatusRequestDetails>
          </ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatusRequest>
        </ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatusReq>
      </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

Stubs I tried:

```
stub_request(:any, /.*.sandbox.paypal.com\/2.0\//).
   with(:body => WebMock::Matchers::HashIncludingMatcher.new({'n2:Action'=>'Cancel'}),
    :headers => {'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
   to_return(:status => 200, ...
```

or

```
stub_request(:any, /.*.sandbox.paypal.com\/2.0\//).
   with(query:
    hash_including({ProfileID: 'sdaddsadsd'}),
    :headers => {'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
   to_return(:status => 200, ...
```

(etc.)

have failed.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you can save your XML to be stubbed into separate XML file (say `request.xml`), it is quite easy:

```ruby
stub_request(:any, 'https://sandbox.paypal.com')
  .with(body: File.read('request.xml').strip)
```

Headers can be omitted.

[How to use webmock regex matcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773895/how-to-use-webmock-regex-matcher) might help you with URL matching.

P.S. `strip` is to remove ending line feed